# Copying Empty dataframe as a redshift table

Tags: python, amazon-redshift

I have a CSV file which I get from the business and contains Risk data.

Sometimes that file have data and sometimes they manually remove all the records from the CSV file.

I have a function which picks the CSV file from folder location copy the file in a Data frame and then have another function which copies that Data frame into a redshift table.

```
def ar_extraction_csv():
# Importing the Critical Problem Unresolved from shared drive
ar_file = r'\Audit_Reporting.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(ar_file, encoding='utf-8')

data_transfer.copy_dataframe(
    df=df1,
    target_table_name='audit_reporting',
    target_schema_name='tp_risk'
)
```

copy_dataframe uses awswrangler to use the redshift.copy command to copy the file into a redshift table.

The issue in the code I am facing is how to make the copy_dataframe function to copy the empty dataframe as a Table in redshift.

Currently I get an error saying "Dataframe cannot be Empty"

We have added a Line in the Copy_dataframe function so it does not proceed further and execute the redshift.copy command if the dataframe is empty.

```
   if not df.shape[0]:
    package.logger.info(f'No values in the dataframe. We do not write to Redshift')
    return
```

But I want all the rows to be deleted in the table if the csv file does not have data in dataframe.

What's the best way to handle this situation.